# Swap does not work in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, swap

I've installed Kubuntu 15.04. It seems that swap doesn't work:
`free -m`:

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3706       3109        596        197         62       1413
-/+ buffers/cache:       1633       2072
Swap:       5721          0       5721
```

Thought the `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` is 60. How to fix it?

**Upd**: yes, it seems that the real used memory is  `used minus cached`, that's why there is no need in swap at the moment.

Comment: Your swap is working normally. You have enough free ram that swap is not needed at this time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There may not be any need to use the swap space, since you've got some free memory. Start some memory intensive applications and see how it goes.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#Why_is_my_swap_not_being_used.3F